# How to get Output parameter from SQL query in F#

Tags: sql, parameters, f#

I have SQL query, where I have two parameters and one output parameter (varchar).
How I should call the procedure and get the output parameter?
Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure but I imagine you are getting down voted as you are expected to at least show what you are tried. Questions of "Tell me how to do X" are generally not well received. Kattarina was nice to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to connect to your db. What technology are you using?

In any case it could be something like that (code is written for c# & Oracle, but it will give you an idea how to solve your case):

```
IDbConnection dbConnection = new OracleConnection(your_connectionstring)
var param = new OracleDyamicParameters(); 
param.Add("out_result", OracleDbType.Int64, ParameterDirection.Output);
string query = "Your_proc_Name";
await SqlMapper.QueryAsync<MyReturnClass>(dbConnection, query, param: param, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
db_res.Result = param.GetOutResult();
```